# Does Apple allow iPhone apps that display images that are pulled from a azure blob storage?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, mobile-application, azure-blob-storage

I am planning to build a mobile app that will need to have access to hundreds of images of items that a contractor would use in doing a repair to an air conditioning system. Instead of adding hundreds of images to the assets of the app and bloating the size of the app, I wanted to put the images in a cloud blob storage like Azure and just pull the image when the item is referenced by the user to look at. My question is does Apple allow an app for the iPhone to do this or do they require developers to have all images inside the app package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're basically asking if you can download image assets on demand, rather than packaging them with the app. You can certainly do that (and Apple offers a number of ways, including raw URL downloads and [On-Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/)) but you should carefully consider the user experience if the app is being used with limited network connectivity.

A caveat: if you roll your own on-demand resource loader, make sure to store the cached images in a directory that is not backed up to iCloud--you don't want to take up your user's iCloud space with images that can easily be retrieved from the network if they are removed.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.